# android:imeOption & imeActionLable does not change keyboard Enter label with Next

Tags: android

I have been trying to figure this out but no success. It seems very simple but I don't know why following two tag of xml (`android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:imeActionLabel="Next"`) in the code does not work.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/stcnTxt" style="@style/DetailFormTextField" android:singleLine="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:imeActionLabel="Next"> </EditText>
```

According to upper code keyboard enter key Label should be replace with Next Label But it still show the enter key on the keyboard. I am using HTC wildfire for output.

Comment: <EditText android:id="@+id/stcnTxt"
    style="@style/DetailFormTextField" android:singleLine="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:imeActionLabel="Next">
   </EditText>

Comment: @Nanne & user1154390 did u tried my answer? or got any other solution? In that case please post it, so that others can get help from that.

Comment: I did not have the problem, so no, I did not try your answer and neither do I have a solution.

Answer (score 13):

I was having something similar problem, but `android:inputType="text"` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

For me, this works on an HTC Evo, but not on a Galaxy S3. I have this code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/decimalFarenheit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/decimalCelsius"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/calculate" >

</EditText>
```

on my Galaxy s3, the text for the send button is "Send". But on the HTC Evo, the text for the send button is "Calculate".

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me when I made it a short message.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/stcnTxt" 
android:singleLine="true" 
android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
android:imeActionLabel="Next"
android:layout_height="150px"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:inputType="textShortMessage"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Vee. I don't know why it does not work for me. I have downloaded few tutorial as well. When I run the tutorial with above xml tags it does not change the enter key with NEXT labl as well.

Comment: Ehh, I've had a lot of trouble with that sort of thing too. The only way I get it to work is by making it a different type of box than it actually is. Try making the inputType an emailAddress or something and see if it changes at all.